# Using new .NET execution environment in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, .net, xamarin, dnx

I'm wondering if a library created with dnx core can be used in Xamarin for developing android and ios apps.

Is it possible? and if it is, can anybody refer me to an example of use?

Comment: No, it doesn't, Xamarin uses the standard .net framework (well, mono in this case), DNX core is a different framework, so no, it will not work.

Comment: @Gusman so why in papers microsoft mentioned that this new library can use in all platforms : [this link](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html)

Comment: no, it says *multiple platforms* not *all platforms*, it's supported on macos, linux and windows, but not on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core BCLs are currently compiled to suit the upcoming .NET Platform Standard. So they can be reused in Xamarin platforms once they are finalized.

But right now nothing is ready yet and you should wait.